# I need to re-render a component that is part of the MainLayout when a button on another component is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following screenshot which is where I need help trying to solve a problem.

The red banner with the timer is part of the mainlayout component which I need to persist throughout the entire site. The purpose of the red banner is to countdown from a specific time which tells the user how long they have to finish their booking on the site. **This counter only starts when the user clicks the Book Dates button at the bottom of the page**.

[image: Screenshot of the main section with the counter.]

The problem I am having is that the component is in the mainlayout component it will only render when there is a full page refresh or you select the address bar and press enter, this component will show and hide properly. If there is no refresh at all you could basically navigate the entire site without this header ever showing up.

How would I get this component to show up when the user clicks on the Book Dates button automatically?

This is the code in my CountdownTimer component:

```
@inject IBookingRepository bookingRepository
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage localStorage
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

@if (booking is not null)
{
    if (booking.CheckInDate != DateOnly.MinValue)
    {
        <div class="timer">
            <p>Current booking time left: @timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss")</p>
        </div>
    }
}

<br />
<br />

@code {
    private TimeSpan timeSpan;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private DateTime startTime;
    private Timer timer;

    private ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> result { get; set; }

    public Booking? booking { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetLocalStorage();

        if (!isRunning && booking.CheckInDate != DateOnly.MinValue)
        {
            StartTimer();
        }
    }

    private async Task GetLocalStorage()
    {
        result = await localStorage.GetAsync<string>(SettingsUtility.sessionId);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            await localStorage.SetAsync(SettingsUtility.sessionId, Guid.NewGuid());
            result = await localStorage.GetAsync<string>(SettingsUtility.sessionId);
        }

        bookingRepository.DeleteStaleBookings();
        booking = bookingRepository.GetBySessionId(Guid.Parse(result.Value));

        if (booking is null)
        {
            booking = new Booking();
            booking.SessionId = Guid.Parse(result.Value);
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        startTime = booking.CreatedDate.AddSeconds(SettingsUtility.bookingTime);
        timer = new Timer(UpdateTime, null, 0, 1000);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        timer?.Dispose();
    }

    private void UpdateTime(object state)
    {
        timeSpan = startTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

        if (timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds < 0)
        {
            StopTimer();
            bookingRepository.DeleteStaleBookings();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my calendar component that contains the Book Dates button:
This component basically renders all the dates and allows the user to navigate through each month.

```
@inject IBookingRepository _bookingRepository

<div class="calendar-days grid-7">

    <CalendarDisabledDays calendarMonth="calendarMonth" offsetDays="offsetDays" />

    @for (int i = startDay; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(calendarMonth.Year, calendarMonth.Month, i);

        <div class="active">
            <button @onclick="() => SetDate(DateOnly.FromDateTime(date))">@i</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div class="calendar-submit grid-1">
    <EditForm OnSubmit="CreateDates" EditContext="editContext">
        <div>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-main" @onclick="ClearDates">Clear Dates<i class="fa-solid fa-eraser btn-icon"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Book Dates<i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-check btn-icon"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int daysInMonth { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool status { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public DateOnly calendarMonth { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int offsetDays { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public BookingDatesVM booking { get; set; }

    private int startDay { get; set; }
    EditContext? editContext;
    ValidationMessageStore? validationMessages;
    bool valid;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        editContext = new(booking);
        validationMessages = new(editContext);

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        SetStartDate();
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the start day of the month. Used primarily if the selected month is the current month we are in.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetStartDate()
    {
        startDay = 1;
        if ((calendarMonth.Month == DateTime.Now.Month) && (calendarMonth.Year == DateTime.Now.Year))
        {
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the date the user selects to the model before saving to the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">The selected date.</param>
    private void SetDate(DateOnly date)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            booking.CheckInDate = date;
        }
        else
        {
            booking.CheckOutDate = date;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the date in the model and sets them to the default MinValue.
    /// </summary>
    private void ClearDates()
    {
        booking.CheckInDate = DateOnly.MinValue;
        booking.CheckOutDate = DateOnly.MinValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the selected dates to the database along with the sessionId.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task CreateDates()
    {
        valid = ValidateForm();

        if (valid)
        {
            await _bookingRepository.CreateAsync(BookingMapper.FromDatesVM(booking));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manual validation of the calendar control used to check whether the dates selected are valid before storing them in the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True is the dates are allowed and false if the dates have some conflict with them.</returns>
    private bool ValidateForm()
    {
        valid = editContext.Validate();
        validationMessages?.Clear();

        var checkOutDate = editContext.Field(nameof(booking.CheckOutDate));
        var checkInDate = editContext.Field(nameof(booking.CheckInDate));

        if (booking.CheckInDate == DateOnly.MinValue)
        {
            validationMessages.Add(checkInDate, "Check in date is required.");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (booking.CheckOutDate == DateOnly.MinValue)
        {
            validationMessages.Add(checkOutDate, "Check out date is required.");
            valid = false;
        }

        return editContext.Validate();
    }
}
```

I have tried applying statehaschanged() on certain parts of the code even tried some cascading parameters to see if i could set a bool to show when the Book Dates button is pressed but i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Dependency injection.  Create a class with a periodic timer, a public method you can use to start the timer, and a public event that you can call from the timer's event handler.  Add the class using `AddService` as a Scoped service to your main app file.  Any page or component that might start the timer can `@inject` the service, allowing you to start your timer.  The Layout page will also `@inject` the service, and will subscribe to your event.

Comment: I've added links to various questions with answers that answer the basic question you're asking - How do I notify a component that something has changed?.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is that we can have a method in MainLayout to call startTimer in Timer component. Then call the Mainlayout method to in your Calendar componeny.

I had a test in my side like below.

CountdownTimer.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<div class="timer">
    <p>Current booking time left: @timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss")</p>
</div>
<br />

@code {
    private TimeSpan timeSpan;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private DateTime startTime;
    private Timer timer;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        startTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
        timer = new Timer(UpdateTime, null, 0, 1000);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        timer?.Dispose();
    }

    private void UpdateTime(object state)
    {
        timeSpan = startTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        if (timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds < 0)
        {
            StopTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

MainLayout

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp2</PageTitle>
<CascadingValue Value="this">
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <CountdownTimer @ref="counttimer" />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
</CascadingValue>


@code {
    CountdownTimer counttimer;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        counttimer.StartTimer();
    }
}
```

Counter.razor

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowTimer">Start Timer</button>
</div>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }

    private void ShowTimer()
    {
        Layout.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Test result.

[image]

If you are also want to control the hide and show of the timer, then we can add `hidden = "@hidetimer"` attribute in  like below.

```
<div hidden="@hidetimer" class="timer">
    <p>Current booking time left: @timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss")</p>
</div>
<br />

@code {
    private TimeSpan timeSpan;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private DateTime startTime;
    private Timer timer;
    private bool hidetimer = true;

public void StartTimer()
{
    hidetimer = false;
    startTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
    timer = new Timer(UpdateTime, null, 0, 1000);
    isRunning = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would never work with a time like this with timer, they are very hard to unit test, here is how i would solve it

create a ITimerService interface

```
public interface ITimerService
{
    event Action<TimerOption> ShowAction;

    void ShowTimer(TimerOption options);
}
```

this is the implementation

```
public class TimerService  : ITimerService
{
    public event Action<TimerOption>? ShowAction;
    public void ShowTimer(TimerOption options)
    {
        if (ShowAction != null)
            ShowAction.Invoke(options);
    }
}
```

this would be your page where you inject that interface and call the ShowAction function

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorAppTimer.Data

@inject ITimerService TimerService

@code {

    private DateTime _startTime;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        var stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        
        var elapsedTime = (stopTime - _startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        
        TimerService.ShowTimer(new TimerOption()
        {
            Info = $"Ellapsed time: {elapsedTime}"
        });
    }

}


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?"/>

<Button onclick="@(() => Start())">Start</Button>
<Button onclick="@(() => Stop())">Stop</Button>
```

And your mainlayout, you also inject the service and you wire up the Action

```
  @using BlazorAppTimer.Data
    @inherits LayoutComponentBase
    
    @inject ITimerService TimerService
    
    @code {
    
        string Info = "---";
        
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            TimerService.ShowAction+= ShowAction;
            base.OnInitialized();
        }
    
        private void ShowAction(TimerOption obj)
        {
            Info = obj.Info;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    
    }
    
    <PageTitle>BlazorAppTimer</PageTitle>
    
    <div class="page">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu/>
        </div>
    
        <main>
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
            </div>
            
            <span>@Info</span>
            <article class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
```